How does speed telemetry displayed in SpaceX live videos work?
How is speed value measured and relative to what?
For instance when looking at ITF5 boost back burn, one can notice the speed reaches a minimum of 1203km/h before increasing again. Booster is still climbing at this point.
This might indicate the considered velocity vector used for telemetry is not aligned with booster's axis. (otherwise it would have reached zero value when changing direction)
Is it aligned to an imaginary straight line connecting launch site to booster? Something else?

The velocity indicated by the speed gauge in the telemetry is true velocity or absolute velocity referenced to the Earth.
This value represents the magnitude of the booster's three-dimensional velocity vector. The reason the speed doesn't reach zero during the boost-back burn is that the rocket continues to ascend even while the burn is ongoing. The boost-back burn primarily affects the horizontal component of the velocity, bringing that part close to zero, but the booster still has vertical motion.
Here's an image of a Falcon 9 booster's approximate flight path:

Although this is for the Falcon 9, not Superheavy, the booster flight paths are similar. As you can see, during the boost-back burn, the rocket is still moving upwards, which is why the absolute velocity doesn't drop to zero.

@user721108 Center of the Earth or any "static" point, it does not matter. As for function, I don't know how exactly SpaceX's flight software stack works, but the simplest solution would just be to use GPS, get the 3d coordinates a couple times a second, and then calculate a velocity vector using the two positions and the delta-t

@Dragongeek I've always wondered why it shows zero before launch while moving at ~400 m/s due to Earth''s rotation; do they smoothly transition from ground speed to "true velocity" somehow?

@uhoh They don't need to for the booster. It can stay in the same frame of reference as the rotating Earth, because it's only landing back at the start in 9-11 minutes. It's a valid question for the second stage though.

@uhoh Commercial GPS receivers report position (and some GPSs report velocity as well) in ECEF. SpaceX makes their own, so there's no telling what their GPS receivers report.

@Dragongeek II would never, ever call that true velocity, let alone absolute velocity. There is no such thing as "absolute velocity", or  "true velocity" for that matter, thanks to Newton and later, to Einstein. SpaceX apparently is reporting Earth-centered, Earth-fixed (ECEF) velocity.

@DavidHammen I suspect the term isn't meant to be a universal object velocity, instead it's probably mainly meant to contrast with other speed measurements such as indicated airspeed. Calling it "ground speed" (the alternative to IAS often used in air travel) isn't sufficient in this case because the vertical component is ignored in calculating ground speed.

@DavidHammen There is a problem here that all speed measurements in aviation nomenclature either do not account for vertical velocity components (ground speed) or they always measure relative to the local volume of air, and thus include wind (airspeed, true airspeed, calibrated airspeed, etc). I use the words "true velocity" and "absolute velocity" to differentiate.
